# iCloud file and sync

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization

I have recently activated iCloud drive sync so, my I have basically uploaded the ~/Documents folder into the cloud. Everything worked as expected and now I can see documents on all my devices.

When I work and I update a file, I see that it is synchronized with Cloud, as expected but, last week, it started to resync all the documents folder instead of the changed only and took one day. Today it still doing again. So, why? Is a normal behavior or a problem? How the sync with cloud algorithm works? The problem I can see is CPU is running at 70% and the fan is running at max speed for hours due to bird process execution.

Comment: Is disk space low in either your iCloud account or your Mac?

Comment: No, 50% free on local disk and 1.8TB available on cloud